# VBE Intellisense: Is it possible to choose constant from drop down list?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

Does VBE Intellisense allows us to choose an Excel constant (xl...) from its dropdown list?

For example, regarding the code below, when I type `r.`, I can choose `Cells` from a drop-down list. Then, typing `.int`, I can choose `Interior` from a drop-down list. Then, typing `.pat`, I can choose `Pattern` from a drop-down list. Then, typing `=` plus space plus `xl` nothing happens.

So, how to choose one of Pattern's constants from VBE Intellisense? Is that possible?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    r.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternCrissCross
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try .Pattern = xlpattern.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vba enumerations you have to know the name of the enumeration, then you can get specific members by intellisense.  In this case your enumeration is xlPattern to you get get the enumeration using

```
r.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlPattern.
```